# NEED trigger in google script when new values are added in a row trigger after 30sec

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Hi all created a initiate mail  need a trigger in app script, This spreadsheet gets data using query function from another spreadsheet. Need to trigger when only new row data is added to the sheet. Need a trigger when new row is added. That data will be taken from another sheet, Or thinking to take this trigger and keep in button format in the sheet where data is coming from

```
function sendEmail() {

 //setup function
 var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 var StartRow = 2;
 var RowRange = ActiveSheet.getLastRow() - StartRow + 1;
 var WholeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(StartRow,1,RowRange,16);
 var AllValues = WholeRange.getValues();

 var message = "";
 //iterate loop
 for (i in AllValues) {

 //set current row
 var CurrentRow = AllValues[i];

 //define column to check if sent (starts from "0" not "1")
 var EmailSent = CurrentRow[14];
 var caseworker = CurrentRow[7];

 //if row has been sent, then continue to next iteration
 if (EmailSent == "sent") 
     continue;

 //set HTML template for information
  message +=
      "<p><b>Bank: </b>" + CurrentRow[0] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Branch: </b>" + CurrentRow[1] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Region: </b>" + CurrentRow[2] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Lan Number: </b>" + CurrentRow[3] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Customer Name: </b>" + CurrentRow[4] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Loan Type: </b>" + CurrentRow[5] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Case Worker: </b>" + CurrentRow[11] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Documents Recieved: </b>" + CurrentRow[6] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Initiated Date: </b>" + CurrentRow[7] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Site Visit Status: </b>" + CurrentRow[8] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Site Visit Date: </b>" + CurrentRow[9] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Site Visit Done by: </b>" + CurrentRow[10] + "</p><br><br>";

  //set the row to look at
  var setRow = parseInt(i) + StartRow;

  //mark row as "sent"
  ActiveSheet.getRange(setRow, 15).setValue("sent");
}
//define who to send grants to
var SendTo = "$$$$$@gmail.com" + "," + "&&&&&@gmail.com" + "," + "@@@@@@@gmail.com"+ "," + "######@gmail.com ";
 
  
 //set subject line
 var Subject = "New case initiated to Veena";


  //send the actual email  
   MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: SendTo,
      cc: "#######@gmail.com",
      subject: Subject,
      htmlBody: message,
});
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable. If you need further help, please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts regarding  Google Apps Script triggers in Google Sheets.

Comment: There is no such trigger unless data is added by a user edit.

Comment: If there is no triggers, then can we stop sending mail process if there is no new column added, this code gives if mail sent it will be giving me column 14 as sent, if all rows which contains data is having sent then mail should not be sent can do that. Thank you

Comment: onEdit trigger is not suitable for this case because data is coming from another sheet. 
But you can trigger your function for instance every day or every x hours and check as you did if the column 15 is not equal to sent.